# Parse JSON string inside of a object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json string inside of a JSON object but continue getting "Unexpected Token" Or "unexpected end of input" errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The syntax looks like so:

```
{
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  company_name: 'TEST',
  sample: 't-e-s-t',
  populated: '{"type":"Select","manualTitle":"Manual Title","manualBody":"Email Message will go here","templateTitle":"Title Here","templateBody":"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old."}',
  messageBody: 'New body test'
}
```

Comment: What does the JS you're using to parse the JSON look like?

Comment: That's a JS object, not a JSON object. (The`populated` property is JSON)

Comment: JSON.parse(obj.populated)

Comment: @Kinglish OP calls their object literal a "JSON object" (which is a term without any right to exist). But yes, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2mqxr0kn/

Answer (score 4):

That's a JavaScript object, not JSON. ([JSON is a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and has a very specific syntax.) So use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the value of the `populated` property of the object, and then you can extract its keys and values.

```js
const obj = {
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  company_name: 'TEST',
  sample: 't-e-s-t',
  populated: '{"type":"Select","manualTitle":"Manual Title","manualBody":"Email Message will go here","templateTitle":"Title Here","templateBody":"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old."}',
  messageBody: 'New body test'
};

const populated = JSON.parse(obj.populated);
console.log(populated.manualBody);
```